# Filling a Fortran 2D array

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am wondering how to fill a 2-dimensional array that's pretty large. I just want to fill it out with X's or a value and print that out.

So far:

```
CHARACTER Grid(20,20)

print *, Grid
```

Comment: Welcome. Please use the provided formatting features for your code and do not add unneeded noise. See the edits I made to your question. It is important to format the code appropriately especially for larger samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be simple. How about the following:

```
program simple
   CHARACTER(len=1) :: Grid(20,20)
   Grid = "x"
   Print *, Grid
end program simple
```

You can test it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php). Note that you have to know/determine the length of the character in advance, otherwise you will have to use an allocatable character array. If you want each element to have a different character length, then you will have to create an allocatable array of allocatable characters, which is possible in Fortran 2003 beyond.